# Responsive Visualforce Pages for Salesforce1

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app

I am using responsive designs to design visualforce pages for Salesforce1 platform. in a page, i have a table, for this i used html  with Data-role as "Collapsible". i am getting the results correctly when the page loaded initially. I have a button on the page, that modifies the table results (here i am re-rendering the table after action completes), but after the page re-rendered i am no longer seeing the collapsible design on the visualforce page which previously had appeared. instead normal table appearing.

i have included jquery mobile libraries this.

================================

## Code

```
<div data-role="collapsibleset" id="set">
            <div data-role='collapsible'  id='panel5' class='selector' >
                <h3>The Line Items</h3>
                ****<table style="display : Block; border-top: 1px solid #d6d6d6;" data-role="table" data-mode="columntoggle" data-column-btn-text="Click me to hide or shown columns!" class="ui-responsive" id="lineItemsTable">****
.
.*/*action method that call apex method and returns back to the page*/*
.
</table>
```

suggest me how shall i retain the collapsible design after the page re-rendered.

Answer (score 0):

To make your VF page more performance on SF1, 
Redesign your page to use RemoteAction method instead of Action Function (Refer : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_example.htm).
It will makes the page data load faster and it will not get into white screen even if you loading large data.

Thanks,
Hari

Comment: i am not getting a white screen after the action completes, rather the designs are disappearing. eg. initially i have collapsible table that allows me to select which column should be displayed on the mobile device page, once i click on the button , action completed, that collapsible feature is not coming again.

Comment: When the action function oncomplete event, try calling collapible refresh  https://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsibleset/#method-refresh

Comment: i am using oncomplete in button to do refresh the collapsible but it does not help either.                                                                                                                  code:function initiatedesign()
            {
                window.alert('entered');
                $( "#set" ).collapsibleset( "refresh" );
            }